# Radix-UI ScrollArea in another ScrollArea

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, react-tsx

How can I change priority of scroll to child ScrollArea from parent ScrollArea?

For example:

```
<ScrollArea>
    <ScrollArea>
                    
    </ScrollArea>
</ScrollArea>
```

When I scroll whole component it scrolls parent ScrollArea? even a cursor on child

I surfed  internet, but no profit